# How to know focus element in recyclerview fullscreen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've set a recyclerview that works fine. I want to know when some element have the focus in the screen. My recyclerview display every item to fullscreen. Is possible to know, in the viewholder or in some place, what's the item that have the focus?

My problem is that I have a countdown in every item. And I only want that the countdown start when the item has the focus.

Comment: Is your application using a keyboard or gamepad for navigation? Or is just touchscreen only?  Does the UI contain EditTexts?  I'm not so certain that any of your displayed views actually have their focus set.

Comment: check my update question. Every item has his own title inside the item

Answer (score 2):

Try calling getFocusedChild():

```
View focusedView = (View) recyclerview.getFocusedChild();
```

Comment: Ok, in what place?

Comment: Probably inside your activity or fragment where you use RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

there is no object supposed to "have" the focus. 
If you want that feature, you need to implement it. 
For example, you can add a member `hasFocus` in your model class, then in your view holder,

```
if (hasFocus) displayWithFocus();
else displayWithoutFocus();
```

Then you must define a view.OnItemClicekListener like this

```
onItemClicked(... View view, position p, ...){
    itemsList.elementAt(p).setHasFocus(true)
}
```

This way you can also define if you want one item or several items to get selected.

To get to know who "has" the focus (is selected), you must iterate through the items list (model side).

edit: focus could only be used for views traversal, or use for example with a keyboard ...

Comment: Not sure if this could be a solution for me. My problem is that I have a countdown in every item. And I only want that the countdown start when the item has the focus.

Comment: Actually you need to define "has the focus", because it is not clear to me the kind of UX you are implementing

Comment: Think in an item that is in a fullscreen. Some items has a countdown. That I don't want is that an item that you are not watching, start his countdown. I'm not if this is a good explanation

Comment: ok, I see. You have a RecyclerView.focusSearch method.
However if you know that there is only one visible view at a given time, you could use the viewholder to start the countdown for that particular view and stop the countdown for all other views (items actually)

Comment: yeah, is only one visible view at a given time. Sorry, but, viewholder is not call every time that you display a item in the screen. Then, how can you know when countdown have to start for this item?